# batch Script Q: How to read an input from a dialog box

Tags: batch-file

I would like to know if there is a way to read a dialog box input ?
For example:

The below command open a dialog box with to buttons "OK" and "Cancel"

> *start /w dialog.exe*

How can I know or read if the user pressed OK or Cancel?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `dialog.exe` isn't a inbuilt command. Where is it's documentation?

Comment: Thanks, Indeed, dialog.exe is not inbuilt. However, it's an external program (written in other lang') which prompts a pop-dialog box.

Comment: How does that program work?

Comment: It's a 3rd party one, I don't have the code. 
That's is my question to understand whether there is an option in Batch to catch the return value of these buttons.

Thanks for answering anyway :)

Comment: How would anyone know? It's trivial to make your own.

Comment: In a vbsfile `WScript.Quit MsgBox("Hi")`. Here's what the return value means. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445082(v=vs.60).aspx